# pass and return references

Tags: c++, reference

I have defined a normal class T:

```
class T { 
  public:
    T() { cout << "default constructor " << this << "\n" }
    T(const & T a) { cout <<"constructor by copy " << this << "\n"}
    ~T() { cout << "destructor "<< this << "\n"}
    T & operator=(T & a) {
      cout << " assignemnt operator :" << this << " = " << &a << endl;}
};
```

And there are 4 functions, one of which is wrong:

```
T f1(T a){ return a; }
T f2(T &a){ return a; }
T &f3(T a){ return a; } 
T &f4(T &a){ return a; }
```

Does anyone know which one is wrong?

Comment: BTW: In `operator=`, `T& a` is usually const.

Comment: This is a poor question - any compiler would have given the answer!

Comment: `T(const & T a)` is gibberish in the class definition of `T`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f3` is wrong, because it is returning a reference to a local object.

Parameters passed by value are copied. Their copies are local to functions to which they are passed - they go out of scope as soon as the function returns.